# How to set a path for directory?

Tags: python, path

I'm getting an error:
Not a directory: '/root/.keras/datasets/mask_detection_dataset/train_set/without_mask'

Here is my code

```
_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1xdjxPV9hT-p9pFZJllpv-3Yjnl3k3JIz'
zip_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('mask_detection_dataset', origin = _URL, extract =True)

base_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zip_dir),'mask_detection_dataset')
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,'train_set')
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,'validation_set')

train_withoutmask_dir = os.path.join(train_dir,'without_mask')
train_withmask_dir = os.path.join(train_dir,'with_mask')
train_impropermask_dir = os.path.join(train_dir,'improper_mask')

validation_withoutmask_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir,'without_mask')
validation_withmask_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir,'with_mask')
validation_impropermask_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir,'improper_mask')

num_withoutmask_tr = len(os.listdir(train_withoutmask_dir))
num_withmask_tr = len(os.listdir(train_withmask_dir))
num_impropermask_tr = len(os.listdir(train_impropermask_dir))
total_tr_imgs = num_withoutmask_tr + num_withmask_tr + num_impropermask_tr


print('Total training without mask images : ', num_withoutmask_tr )
print('Total training with mask images : ', num_withmask_tr )
print('Total training with improper mask images :', num_impropermask_tr )
print('Total training images : ', total_tr_imgs)
```

[Error :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFHsE.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! In situations where you're stuck with an error and need to ask about it, it helps to create a [mre] that _others can run_ to replicate your problem. Generally, path issues are hard to replicate because nobody else has access to your files, so reducing to minimal code helps. In this case, all you need to do to replicate the error is: `train_withoutmask_dir = '/root/.keras/datasets/mask_detection_dataset/train_set/without_mask'; num_withoutmask_tr = len(os.listdir(train_withoutmask_dir))`. The error is unrelated to `tensorflow` or `face`. Are you sure that directory exists?

Comment: Since you're new here, I recommend you take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)